# File creation date is showing as 1970-01-01 00:00:00 in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python script which lists all the file details(not directories) recursively from a root directory.I am on windows.

```
import sys,os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

root = r"C:\Users\ron\Downloads\xyz"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        fp = os.path.join(path, name)
        try:
            ctime = os.path.getctime(name)
        except OSError:
            ctime = 0
        created_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(ctime)
        print(name,path,os.path.getsize(fp),created_date)
```

name path size is fine but created date is showing as `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `os.path.getctime(name)` should be `os.path.getctime(fp)`

Comment: There's some exception raising which is setting `ctime` to 0. When you do `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` it will return the date to be `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: @Rawing ahh that's the mistake I did. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rawing but why it is adding the number `281093` at the end of the string `2017-09-12 22:33:55.281093` If it is the timestamp then how can I get rid of this.

Comment: Those are *milliseconds*. If you don't like them, custom `strftime` your datetime object.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getctime(name)` returns the time passed in seconds from the current epoch. The epoch starts at `1970-01-01 00:00:00` so if it returns the start of the epoch then `ctime = 0`, which means that you have an OSError.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error may be at line number 11.

Change it with this and working fine.

`ctime = os.path.getctime(fp)`